# Shouldn't tan(π/2) = ∞?

Tags: limits, trigonometry

We will first prove that $\sin(x)/\cos(x) = \tan(x)$.

By definition, $\sin(x) = O/H$, $\cos(x) = A/H$ and $\tan(x) = O/A$, where $O$,$A$ and $H$ are the opposite, adjacent and hypotenuse of a right angled triangle.

$\sin(x)/\cos(x) = O/H ÷ A/H = O/H × H/A = OH/AH = O/A = \tan(x)$

So $\tan(π/2) = \sin(π/2)/\cos(π/2) = 1/0$, which is undefined. However, we know that it can either be $∞$ or $-∞$. Therefore, $\tan(π/2)$ is equal to $∞$ or $-∞$.

If $\tan(π/2) = -∞$, then the limit of $\arctan(x)$ as $x$ approaches $-∞$ should equal $π/2$. However, it equals $-π/2$ instead. Therefore, $\tan(π/2)$ cannot be $-∞$, so it must be $∞$.

Is there any mistake in my working?

Comment: How do you know that it can be $\infty$ or $-\infty$? If a function is undefined at a point, then it is undefined there. Undefined does not equal infinities.

Comment: division by 0 is not defined so you can't just determine whether it would be $\infty$ or $-\infty$. If you take $$\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{1}{x}$$ it equals $\infty$ and if you take the limit i.e. $$\lim_{x\to 0^-} \frac{1}{x}$$ then it equals $-\infty$. And since the left and the right hand limits don't coincide, the limit i.e. $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{x}$$ does not exist. Which proves that, division by 0 isn't defined.

Comment: @ultralegend5385 I know this because tan(π/2) = 1/0, and since the left and right hand limits of 1/x as x approaches 0 are equal to  -∞ and ∞, 1/0 can either be ∞ or -∞.

Comment: It's a matter of $2$-sided limits needing to behave the same on each side. Since $\lim_{x\to(\pi/2)^\pm}\tan x=\pm\infty$, we have two well-defined $1$-sided limits, but $\lim_{x\to\pi/2}\tan x$ is undefined because $+\infty\ne-\infty$.

Comment: @RyanG         If you input larger and larger negative numbers, atan(x) will be closer and closer to −π/2.

Comment: @MathGeek Right; $\arctan(x)$ has range $(-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2).$  Consider also that $\arctan(\frac\pi2+0.00001)=-99999.999997.$  So, directly addressing your title question: $\arctan(x)$ approaches either $\infty$ or $-\infty$, depending on which side $x$ approaches $\frac\pi2$ from.   [(graph)](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ys2fmn5205)

Comment: @MathGeek: If you talked to the angles in the Second Quadrant (who know nothing about angles in the other Quadrants), what would *they* say $\tan(\pi/2)$ should be?

Comment: We *can* introduce a point $\infty$ and say $\tan(\frac\pi2)=\infty$. With the right notion of distance on $\mathbb R\cup\{\infty\}$, this extended version of $\tan$ is even continuous. And we can even extend $\tan$ to the complex plane and $\mathbb R\cup\{\infty\}$ to $\mathbb C\cup\{\infty\}$ to get a holomorphic function. So your idea is very reasonable. It's just not usually done in lower level courses.

Comment: @MathGeek: As many others have already pointed out, $$f(a)=\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$$ for any arbitrary $f$ and $a$ is valid iff $f$ is continuous at $x=a$, which is not the case here (the limit does not even exist here!) This is a removable discontinuity (not exactly, it is if you define $\infty$ to be some point), but that would be a different function than $\tan$, you can call for which an extended $\tan$.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos Since tan(π/2) = 1/0, does this mean that 1/0 = ∞?

Comment: The precise way to say it would be that the continuous extension of $x\mapsto\frac1x$ as a function to the extended real line maps $0\mapsto\infty$. This continuous extension has so many good properties that it would in a way be reasonable to just say $\frac{1}{0}=\infty$, but the issue is that we are also often considering a different kind of extension of the real line, which also contains $-\infty$. And with this different extension, the map from above can't be extended continuously. Due to this, it's better to be very context sensitive when considering such extensions.

Comment: Cutting to the chase: I would refrain from saying $\frac{1}{0}=\infty$, unless the context of the extended real line is crystal clear.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos So if we are working in the extended real number line, 1/0=∞ ?

Comment: Then that would be a reasonable definition to make, yes.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos But if 1/0 = ∞ then 1 = 0 * ∞. Is this allowed in the extended real number line?

Comment: The extended number line is not a field, meaning that it doesn't play nicely with algebra. It does play nicely with geometry, though. And division on the number line shouldn't be interpreted as the inverse operation to multiplication, but as a geometric operation: the extended number line can be visualized as a circle, with 0 on the bottom, $\infty$ at the top, 1 to r right and -1 to the left. $\frac1x$ should be interpreted as mirroring each point at the axis going through 1 and -1. Not as the multiplicative inverse of $x$.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos Do you know a reliable website where I can learn more about the extended real number line?

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos Also, are we talking about the projectively extended real number line or the affinely extended real number line?

Comment: Not really. But if you want to search for yourself, you should look for projective geometry. The extended real line is also known as the projective real line.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos Actually, when I said 1/0 = ∞, I meant 1/0 = +∞.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos Also, can we continue this discussion in chat?

Comment: Yes, we can do that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128619/discussion-between-mathgeek-and-vercassivelaunos).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's clear a few things up. Unless you're working in nonstandard analysis (which I would avoid if I were you!) the statement
$$\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=\infty$$
Is nonsense. When dealing with limits, there are two possibilities:

- The limit exists and is equal to some real number $L$. ($\boldsymbol \infty$ **is not a real number!**)
- The limit doesn't exist.

However, in mathematics, the statements
$$\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=\infty~~~\text{and}~~~\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=\text{undefined}$$
Have slightly different implications, even though the one on the left is, as of now, *nonsense*. Let's define what the left statement means. When we say
$$\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=\infty$$
What we really mean is this:

> $\exists\delta\in\mathbb{R}$ s.t $\forall \epsilon<\delta$, $\exists M\in\mathbb{R}$ s.t $f(x)> M$ for all $x$ satisfying $|x-x_0|<\epsilon$.

Similarly the statement $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=-\infty$ means

> $\exists\delta\in\mathbb{R}$ s.t $\forall \epsilon<\delta$, $\exists M\in\mathbb{R}$ s.t $f(x)\color{red}{\boldsymbol <} M$ for all $x$ satisfying $|x-x_0|<\epsilon$.

Neither of these apply to your case (prove this!) so all we can say is
$$\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=\text{undefined}$$

Comment: If we work in the extended real number line, ∞ is a real number.

Answer (score 0):

What @ultralegend5385 has said is pretty much correct. You cannot define $\infty$ as `undefined` (ie, $\infty$ ≠ `undefined`). The term `undefined` basically denotes that the value does not exist, whereas $\infty$ is way of saying something is endless.

For example, say an arbitrary function $f(x)$ has the domain (-$\infty$, $\infty$). It's just stating the function is endless. Now, that is not the same as being `undefined`, is it?

From what I believe, you might be looking for the word `asymptote` or `asymptotic` in terms of a graph:

The graph of $y = \tan{x}$ has the first, positive asymptote at $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and then for every $\pm \pi$ recurring after that.

[image: Graph]

Answer (score 0):

There are other great answers, yet I will like to present my explanation, which I believe adds to the post.

First of all, what is $\tan$? Well, certainly, it can be defined in terms of right triangles or circles, but to be "standard" let's use the definition:
$$\tan:\,\mathbb{R}\mapsto\mathbb{R}; \tan x:=\dfrac{\sin x}{\cos x}$$
(Note that I used the domain and codomain to be $\mathbb{R}$, presuming that's what you should be using.)

Now, clearly the fraction on the right is a real number when the denominator is not zero i.e. $\cos x\neq 0$ is the restriction for our function. What you did is didn't notice that and put $\cos x=0$. A zero in the denominator should be a red flag in the first place that things aren't right. So, the actual domain should be $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{x:\cos x=0\}$. (This simply means all values from $\mathbb{R}$ except those at which $\cos$ becomes zero.)

Coming to your second point, this is a common misconception that students have, namely they say that $1/0=\infty$ (or put a $\pm$, doesn't change the point). Remember it, **division by zero is not allowed**. (There are certain aspects of this, which you should not care about as of now.) So, basically
$$\dfrac10\color{red}{\neq}\infty$$
And definitions matter in math. You are not allowed to put that $\pi/2$ in place of the $x$ in $\tan x$, because it's defined that way!

As I said in the comments,
$$f(a)=\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$$
is not true for any $f$ and $a$; it's in fact the definition of continuity (in limit terms), the above condition defines that $f$ is continuous at $x=a$. Here, $\tan x$ is not continuous at $x=\pi/2$. If you've learnt about it, you can notice the type of discontinuity.

Hope this helps. Ask anything if not clear :)

Comment: Nice answer. But I find the fragment "presuming that's what you should be using" unclear. Maybe edit it to clarify its meaning?

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider a point $P$ in the unit circle whose coordinate is $(\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$ for $0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$. Now, draw a line that passes through the points $(0,0)$ and $P$. Solving for the equation, we have
\begin{align*}
    y - 0 &= \left(\frac{\sin\theta - 0}{\cos\theta - 0}\right)(x - 0) \\
    y &= \left(\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}\right)x \\
    y &= (\tan\theta)x
\end{align*}

Now, as $\theta < \frac{\pi}{2}$ approaches $\frac{\pi}{2}$, the slope increases without bound. Also, as $\theta > \frac{\pi}{2}$ approaches $\frac{\pi}{2}$, the slope decreases without bound. If $\tan\theta$ is continuous from $\theta_1 = \theta < \frac{\pi}{2}$ to $\theta_2 = \theta > \frac{\pi}{2}$, then for $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}$, $\tan\theta$ must be something in between $\tan\theta_1$ and $\tan\theta_2$. However, almost all real numbers are a candidate for $\tan\theta$ and if it *does* equal a finite value, $m$, then as $\theta_1$ approaches $\frac{\pi}{2}$, $\tan\theta_1$ should decrease to equal $m$. We know that $\tan\theta_1$ increases as $\theta_1$ approaches $\frac{\pi}{2}$ which is a contradiction. Furthermore, as $\theta_2$ approaches $\frac{\pi}{2}$, $\tan\theta_2$ must increase to equal $m$ which is also not the case.

Therefore, we can say that $\tan\theta$ is undefined for $\frac{\pi}{2}$.